# Использование множественного числа в именовании структур данных в Си подобных языках

Tags: c++, c, переменные, структуры-данных, именование

Как бы вы назвали переменную, которая в себе содержит множество(массив/множество) конфигураторов уровней?

- levelsConfigurators
- levelConfigurators
- levelsConfigurator
- Ваш вариант...

В английском, если я правильно понимаю это бы было названо: "configurators of levels", но "red hats"(красные шляпы).

PS

Вопрос очень давно зреет в моем не окрепшем уме. Если вы сможете мне порекомендовать более подходящее место для задания подобного вопроса, буду благодарен. Если кто встречал описание моего случая в гадах, дайте, пожалуйста, ссылочку.

Comment: Как вам нравится так и называйте, не критично если ваш код не будет использоваться как общедоступный API.

Comment: а что за конфигураторы такие ? Не фабрики уровней `factory`?

Comment: @LLENN хотелось бы чтобы этот код было не стыдно показать коллегам/при приеме на работу. Пишу бесплатную игру, думаю со временем выложить исходники на гитхаб.

Comment: @vegorov просто пытаюсь следовать Dependency Injection, передаю конфигураторы в init. Не факт, что подход себя оправдает, но думаю его стоит опробовать.

Comment: Имхо - `levelConfigurators`. Интересно, грамматически какой-то один вариант правильный, или оба?..

Comment: Если других конфигураторов нет, то назовите этот массив просто `Cfg` (где-то внутри цикла `... levelConfigurators[currentLevel] ...` на мой вкус просто ужасно)

Comment: [Complex variable name with plural nouns](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/344759/complex-variable-name-with-plural-nouns)

Comment: `configurators_of_levels` конечно же!

Comment: В английском "configurators of levels" взаимозаменяемо с "level configurators", а вместо "red hats" можно сказать "hats of red", хотя последняя форма прозвучит вычурно архаично/поэтично.

Comment: `Leve1s_c0nf1gurat0rs` :) Но еще круче - `konfiguratory_urovnej` :)

Answer (score 1):

Если переменная хранит несколько конфигураторов, каждый из который отвечает за один уровень, то ваш вариант - `levelConfigurators`.

Если каждый конфигуратор отвечает за несколько уровней, то в этом случае лучше было бы использовать `levelsConfigurators`.